# Angular Projects: Sharing Data Models

Tags: angular, angular-cli, project, workspace

I have an Angular workspace that contains 3 projects:

- wr-admin (application)
- wr-client (application)
- wr-core (library)

wr-core is for shared services, components and data models.

In wr-core, I have created the following folder:

```
/lib/data
```

In this, I have a number of data models.

I bundled these in a separate file called `wr.models.ts` and then exported this bundle through `public_api.ts`.

**wr.models.ts**

```
export * from './entity.model';
export * from './party.model';
export * from './person.model';
export * from './organisation.model';
export * from './party-role.model';
export * from './role-type.model';
```

**public_api.ts**

```
export * from './lib/wr-core.service';
export * from './lib/wr-core.component';
export * from './lib/wr-core.module';
export * from './lib/data/wr.models';
```

I built this library using:

```
ng build wr-core
```

I imported the library into app.module.ts:

```
import { WrCoreModule } from 'wr-core';

...
  imports: [ WrCoreModule ],
...
```

I then get this error:

```
ERROR in : Error: Module not found: WrCoreModule
```

I've also tried the following with no success:

```
import { WrCoreModule } from 'wr-core/wr-core';
import { WrCoreModule } from 'wr-core/public_api';
```

wr-core is listed in tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
  "wr-core": [
    "dist/wr-core"
  ],
  "wr-core/*": [
    "dist/wr-core/*"
  ]
}
```

My question is, how can I use a library to store shared data models?

I want to use this approach because the same data models will be used in `wr-admin`. Not only this, but I'll be adding my API services and so forth to `wr-core` so that they can also be shared between applications.

Comment: You don't need to build the library if you're not publishing it. In your tsconfig (top level one) you add paths that point to the public-api files `"@mycompany/lib": ["./lib/src/public_api.ts"]`. It's a convention to add scoped names in case you ever decide to publish internally or to npm. In your apps then use `import { IUserServive } from "@mycompany/lib/models"`

Comment: Try npm-pack. This will create a .tgz file that you can reference in your package.json/dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Are your models plain typescript classes? In that case, why do you build a module after all?

In my projects I usually share code between mulitple client applications or client/server by simply importing the typescript files, and adding the respective part to your `tsconfig.json`'s `include` property.

Let's say your folder structure looks like this:

```
- project1
  - tsconfig.json
- project2
  - tsconfig.json
- your-library
  - file1.ts
  - file2.ts
  - ...
```

You can then just import the `.ts` files in your angular applications, and include them for the compilation process in each project's `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {...}
  "include": [
    "./",
    "../your-library/**/*",
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good option for static files. What I'd like to do eventually though is build core services into the library as well. I'm using different projects for client and admin so they can eventually be served from different sub-domains. The data layer will have models and services for working with Google Firestore. I'd like to centralize all of this code. Also, because the data models are universal, I'd like to bundle the library to be used in other projects/workspaces by publishing it.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question, the models are plain Typescript interfaces & classes. I'm still not 100% on how I'm going to implement them as I'm looking at various techniques to make them flexible and API-friendly. Using a hydration strategy looks like an option, but I'm still researching other methods that may be more suitable.